# SELECT UNION as DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, union, distinct

How do I perform a DISTINCT operation on a single column after a UNION is performed?

```
T1
--
ID Value 
1  1
2  2
3  3

T2
--
ID Value
1  2
4  4
5  5
```

I am trying to return the table:

```
ID Value
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Value 
FROM (SELECT*FROM T1 UNION SELECT*FROM T2) AS T3
```

This does not seem to work.

Comment: "This does not seem to work." - in what way?

Comment: You are not giving us all the details, will the value always has to be the same as field 1, min value, max value, random value...Any way distinct is on all the fields, not just one field.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I can say, there's no "one-column `distinct`": `distinct` is always applied to a whole record (unless used within an aggregate like `count(distinct name)`). The reason for this is, SQL cannot guess which values of `Value` to leave for you—and which to drop. That's something you need to define by yourself.

Try using `GROUP BY` to ensure  `ID` is not repeated, and any aggregate (here `MIN`, as in your example it was the minimum that survived) to select a particular value of `Value`:

```
SELECT ID, min(Value) FROM (SELECT * FROM T1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM T2) AS T3
GROUP BY ID
```

Should be exactly what you need. That is, it's not the same query, and there's no `distinct`—but it's a query which would return what's shown in the example.

Comment: you sure that's the same query?

Comment: I'd suggest using `UNION ALL` in the subquery as there is no point in doing a `DISTINCT` twice.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm sure it's not—but it's a query which would return what's shown in the example.

Comment: @MitchWheat: It isn't, but it'll do what the OP specifically said he wanted in his "I'm trying to return the table" table.

Comment: On that size data set, I'm not sure it's 100% valid.

Comment: I just tried alf's code. The Group By function does the trick

Answer (score 49):

Why are you using a sub-query? This will work:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION
SELECT * FROM T2
```

`UNION` removes duplicates. (`UNION ALL` does not)

Comment: Point was, OP wanted something called "one-field DISTINCT", and there's no such a concept.

Comment: If you UNION records [1, 1] and [1, 2], you will get both in the result set. OP wanted no repeats from the first column. Obviously this answer was helpful to a lot of people, but I don't think it answers what was asked.

Comment: @user7733611 Actually, you're right now that I examine OP's example data. This query is the refactored equivalent of OP's query.

Answer (score 6):

I think that's what you meant:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T1
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM T2 
  WHERE (
    **ID
** NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM T1)
  );
```

Comment: I really think this should be the accepted answer to the question. It lets you prioritize which table gets values chosen from instead of doing a MIN() with a GROUP BY. Depends on how OP wanted to choose the Value.

Answer (score 4):

This - even  though this thread is way old - might be a working solution for the question of the OP, even though it might be considered dirty.

We select all tuples from the first table,
then adding (union) it with the tuples from the second table limited to those that doe not have the specific field matched in the first table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T1
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM T2 
  WHERE (
    Value NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM T1)
  );
```